# How do I obtain data from Firebase database without an event being triggered?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app for a school project and I have some issues getting data from the Firebase database. I have some data stored in the database that I need to retrieve. However, in the guide I only seem to find information on how to get data when an event is triggered. What I want is for the data to be retrieved automatically e.g. when I open the homescreen of the app or when i scroll down the window to update the homescreen.

It is very possible that there is an explanation to this in the guide, but if so, I have not been able to grasp it. So a thorough description of the solution would be very much appreciated!

regards,
Andreas

Comment: Take the [5 minute Firebase tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial) for the quickest introduction of how Firebase retrieves data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature of Firebase this is the only possible way to retrieve your data.

When you make a request to your Firebase, the data isn't instantly available. When the data becomes available, Firebase will trigger the event and pass you the data. Unfortunately there is no way around this.

People usually deal with this by showing some sort of activity indicator until the data has been retrieved.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab a current snapshot of your data at that moment in time then use [Firebase.once()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html) unlike Firebase.on() it doesn't listen for an event it simply grabs all the data at the location when it is triggered (which in your case could be on document.ready)

Example:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/")

firebaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  // log all the data
  console.log(snap.val())
});
```

Comment: The `Firebase.once()` method isn't android-java.

Comment: Sorry, missed the tag in the question.